# The 32Bit Range

Tags: java

```
class Solution {
    public int reverse(int x) {
        int n = 0;
         for(;x != 0;n=((n * 10) + x % 10),x /= 10);
        if(n < -(int)Math.pow(2,31) || n > ((int)(Math.pow(2,31) - 1)))
        return 0;
        return n;
    }
}
```

This is my code for reversing a number, this is a question on leetcode. The question tells me to not allow the output value to go outside the the 32 bit range, which I have implemented by using the if statement. Yet, when I hit submit, I get this.

[image]

Comment: `The question tells me to not allow the input value to go outside the the 32 bit range, which I have implemented in the if statement.` An int has 32 bits. There is literally no way that value could go outside the 32 bit range.

Comment: Assuming you mean [this question](https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-integer/), it says to return 0 if the _result_ would go outside the 32-bit range, not if the input does. As @tkausl pointed out, it's impossible by definition for the input to exceed that range.

Comment: This is more just a misread of the question, it just wants you to return 0 if the OUTPUT exceeds this range, not the input ( as already mentioned, it is impossible for an input to exceed this anyways)

Comment: By the way, [`Math`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html) offers `exact` methods to notify when overflow happens.

Comment: I've changed the code to make it check the output, yet the same error. BTW, as I am using int, shouldn't the output also not have the chance to exceed the 32-bit range?

Comment: @user13387446 The number `1,543,236,469` in reverse would be `9,646,323,541`. However, this number cannot be saved in an `int` variable, as the upper limit of `int` is `2,147,483,647`. That is the requirement that your code should check for that situation and should return `0` instead of a value it cannot returned.

Comment: If you handle the data type correctly, your number reverse will work. int cannot handle 9646323541, so use the long data type. you for loop last step exceeds the int range, hence your result is incorrect.

Comment: `if (x > 0 && n > 214748364 || x > 7 && n = 214748364) then bail` That covers the positive range. Negative is similar.

Comment: You can run through the loop nine times without overflowing. It's the last pass that will catch you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct way to avoid the breach of `int` data type range and return the zero as expected by that question. You need to check if the range is exceeding *before* it occurs, so you need to have a body for the for loop and perform that check.

```
public int reverse(int x)
        {
            long n = 0;
            for (; x > 0; n = ((n * 10) + x % 10), x /= 10)
            {
                if ((n * 10) > (Math.pow(2, 31)-1 ) )
                {
                    //exceeds range
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            
            return (int)n;
        }
```

Comment: BTW `Math.Pow`  should be `Math.pow` ; and `Math.pow(2, 31)-1` is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

Comment: right, I wrote it up in C# just to show the logic, and the key thing to check before exceed happens.

Comment: Wouldn't the n * 10 test overflow?

Comment: Problem source says to assume no 64bit integers. OP didn't state that though it's implied by the problem itself in my mind.

Comment: Second comment has a link to Leetcode where that restriction is noted. That's what I meant by "problem source".

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution {
    public int reverse(int x) {
        //Integer max value is +2147483647
        //Integer min value is -2147483648
        int n = 0;
        for(;x != 0;n=((n * 10) + x % 10),x /= 10){
          if ((x > 0 && n > 214748364) || (x > 7 && n == 214748364))
            return 0;
          else if (x < 0 && n < -214748364 || x <-8 && n == -214748364)
            return 0;
        }
        return n;
    }
}
```

This works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).